# How to use chartkick line_chart's with dependent models in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, chartkick

I have two models with a `belongs_to` relationship:

```
class Keyword < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :positions
  validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end

class Position < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :keyword
  validates :value, presence: true #this is an integer
  validates :keyword_id, presence: true
end
```

And I want to create a `line_chart` based in minutes of a Keyword's positions value by the `created_at` field.

So I'm trying something like:

```
<%= line_chart @keyword.positions.value %>
```

And I get an error:

```
undefined method `value' for #<Position::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy
```

Well of course, `:value` is a field of an instance of a `Position` not of a collection so how would it be possible to show a chart by minutes of a Keyword's position?

Comment: ON which attribute you want to make line chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my understandings from question

```
<%= line_chart @keyword.positions.group(:created_at).count(:value) %>
```